# PHP imagettftext(): No character set found in

Tags: php, gd, imagettftext

I'm having a weird problem with PHP imagettftext function. I copied an example from php.net and changed **$font** to my own.

Error is

**Warning: imagettftext(): No character set found in [my location] on line 25 Warning: No character set found in  in [my location]**

the problem is that this works fine on my desktop and other servers.

I'm using an example from https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php

I even checked **is_file($font);** to make sure that PHP can read the file.

What should I check more?!

Comment: Can we see the exact code you're using? Custom $font and all?

Comment: @Different55 // actually it was my font file. I switched with a new one and it works fine now.